# How to prepare outlook for exchange to googleapps migration

Tags: backup, gmail, exchange

I am switching over roughly 15 users to googleapps, with everyone still using outlook. The migration from exchange to google will happen via individual .pst files syncing to google then pullen down in to outlook from google. 
We are in the backup phase, and wondering the best practice for appending the .pst's. How are new messages added? I have been going the route of backing up to the same .pst, opting to "allow duplicates" and wondering if this the best to add new messages since the last backup.
We are on outlook 2010.
Any other suggestions on securing backups is welcome.

Comment: Have you considered performing the mailbox backups through your Exchange server?

Comment: Don't have access to the exchange server, and our admins want it done via outlook .pst, sync with gmail, then download back to outlook once gmail servers are active.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a hard cut-off where PSTs are created and uploaded to Google same-day.  You would possibly have messages arrive during/after the PST migration but likely, they would be few.  I would think that the duplicate message option could cause some confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Never messed with Google Apps, but the below logic is sound enough:

Set Outlook to deliver mail to the PST instead of the Exchange mailbox for now.

Then setup their mailboxes in google apps and "migrate" mail flow (SMTP) to point to Google Apps.

Verify new mail is flowing into their Google Apps mailbox(es).

Setup Outlook with a new profile to connect to their Google Apps mailbox.

Sync the (now static) PST file used with Exchange to Gmail/GoogleApps mailbox.

(unless there's some reason why Google Apps wouldn't allow for the above or your own internal processes won't allow for it, it's logic is generic enough it should work fine.